# Make Google Duo audio/ video call on button click

Tags: java, android, google-duo

I can successfully open Google DUO but I want to initialize audio/video call on selecting a particular contact.

```
  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.tachyon");
    launchIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567"));
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
    }
```

My log file shows this.

```
06-17 12:43:37.813 28656-28656/com.example.waheed.duo V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@68d2df8

Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:53818311 intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
dat=tel:xxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.google.android.apps.tachyon 
cmp=com.google.android.apps.tachyon/.MainActivity }
```